# In the game loop, apply dt before the loop starts, or after it finishes?

Tags: game-loop

Say I have a Game class with an update loop that receives a time increment `dt` by parameter.
I was wondering if it's better or customary to apply this dt before the loop starts or after the loop finishes.

```
class Game
{
    void Update(float dt); 
    float m_time; 
}
```

`dt` is the delta time from last update loop.

`m_time` is the total accumulated time since the game started running.

Option 1:

```
void Game::Update(float dt)
{
    m_time += dt;
    /*
    do stuff
    */
}
```

- Pros: I think it's more clear.
- Cons: No update loop is processed at `m_time = 0`. The very first update loop already has `m_time = dt`.

Option 2:

```
void Game::Update(float dt)
{
    /*
    do stuff
    */
    m_time += dt;
}
```

- Pros: The update loop starts at `m_time = 0`.
- Cons: I find it a bit weird that the time is updated after all the processing has finished.

Any advise on which option is better or preferred over the other?

Comment: What is dt and what is m_time?

Comment: Edit that into your question so I can take back the down vote. It's a good question and I feel bad for giving it -1.

Comment: I've improved variables descriptions in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dt, which I'm assuming is the time between frames, should be added to m_time at the beginning of the frame so that m_time will be the time since the start of the game when you use it later on in the frame, assuming that's what m_time is.

Comment: Yeah, `dt` is the time delta between frames, and `m_time`, in this simple example I set, is obviously the accumulated time since the game started. From your answer, I imply that the game will never have an update loop with `m_time = 0`, which is what I find a bit weird. Can't this cause strange effects? For example, animations that don't start playing from the beginning.

Comment: It's just better to be explicit about these things even though intuiting them is easy (but maybe not to someone who hasn't seen dt before). When adding dt before the frame processes, m_time will be 0 for the first frame processes. Naturally, dt should be 0 when the game starts and 0 + 0 = 0. Actually, dt is undefined for the first frame but in application, 0 works fine.